# Vue change global color variables after login

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

i'm looking for ideas on how to completely repaint a website. We use vue with nuxt and sass with sass variables and bootstrap. I need to change the complete colors on the web after logging in, ideally just to change the sass variables file ... somehow. In main.scss all scss are imported and main.scss is imported in nuxt app.js. Any ideas?

EDIT

the correct solution is to use the css variables as follows

```
:root {
  --color-primary: limegreen;
}

.application {
  color: var(--color-primary);
}

.application.dark {
  --color-primary: green;
}
```

after changing the class, the color changes, but now i get an error this one

Custom property ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element

I tried to use it in main.js and directly in the component but still have the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: why dont you use native CSS variables? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp you can change them with javascript easelie

Answer (score 0):

You can not dynamically change sass variables in javascript. To do that you need define your variables in css root for example:

```css
:root {
  
  --main-color: blue;
}
```

And then you can manipulate it in you login method or action wherever you send the request. Like this:

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-color', 'red');
```

Comment: the problem is that we have to use scss not css

Comment: Why? You can always write css in scss files but i think you used sass variables for everything so you need to rewrite all those variables... Anyway if you can do what @Ifaruki says: `$variable = var(--some-color)`otherwise idk any other solution. You can create specific classes for each color but instead of it better rewrite variables in css root instead of sass variables.

Answer (score 0):

I always do it like this:

I go to my `/layouts` folder to `default.vue`. Depending on your project you might use something different then `default.vue`

Then i declare my CSS vars in the `<style>` tag like:

```
:root {
  --main-color: #317EEB;
}
```

This is global available without SASS or any preprocessors.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-color', 'red');
```

You can do it from anywhere you want. Just be sure this gets executed on the client side

```
if (process.client) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-color', 'red');
}
```

```js
function changeColor(variable, color) {
   document.documentElement.style.setProperty(variable, color);
}

button.onclick = function() {
   changeColor("--main-color", "red");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #317EEB;
}

body {
   background: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

Whenever you change the CSS variable the colors updates everywhere

Comment: the problem is that we have to use scss not css

Comment: @DominikDravecký hmm ok. are you able to do something like this? https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2621#issuecomment-438096238

Comment: @DominikDravecký something like `$variable = var(--some-color)` otherwise i dont know.

Comment: i tried to put css into scss like that 

:root {
    --pc-opp-255: #9646aa;
}

and I used it in the component like this 
    background-color:  var(--pc-opp-255);
it works but when i try to change the color from javascript like this 
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--pc-opp-255', 'blue');

 nothing happens

Comment: no, it just doesn't change anything, it just sets in html
<html class = "sr" style = "- pc-opp-255: blue;">

Comment: @DominikDravecký ok, try an queryselector `document.querySelector(":root").style.setProperty()`

Comment: does not work, I'm trying something else, I added in default.vue class like .dark and in main.scss i added this

.application {
 color: var(--pc-opp-255);
  }
  
  .application.dark {
 --pc-opp-255: green;
  }
it should work, but I'm still getting this error

 Custom property ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element (.application.dark { ... --pc-opp-255: ... })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222922/discussion-between-dominik-dravecky-and-ifaruki).